# Why does F#’s Collections.Seq module basically reimplement all the Enumerable extension methods?

Tags: f#, language-design, api-design

Why does the [`Collections.Seq` module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx) have lots of methods that appear to be equivalent to extension methods declared in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx)? Why did the designers of F# feel the need to create a new namespace and new/different names for all of these instead of reusing what already exists in .NET?

(If they needed some extra methods, why didn’t they just add them to `System.Linq.Enumerable`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some other decent answers here, but my take is briefly

- partial application (.NET methods are tupled, F# methods are curried)
- overloading (.NET methods are overloaded, F# let-bound values cannot be)

Basically, once you're accustomed to F# idioms, you'll discover that the .NET APIs kind of suck for F#-style programming.  F# is heavily geared towards pipeline-style programming (which requires partial application of the incoming sequence as the last curried argument) and type-inference (which interacts badly with overloading).

So F# has its own library which works well with F#.  (Here's a quickie decoder-ring [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/12/02/mapping-linq-to-f.aspx).)

Comment: Agreed. In F#-land, the Seq module is far superior to the Linq extension methods. In fact my inclination is to write similar modules for any .NET APIs that I make heavy use of from F#.

Answer (score 7):

Because LINQ methods are located in System.Core => are available only on .NET 3.5 and higher and F# base library supports .NET 2.0+.

Additionaly usage style of Seq functions (through pipeline) is more natural for F# code that dot style of LINQ Enumerable extensions.

Answer (score 6):

Another one reason is using pipeline operators (|>, <|, >>) in F#.

.NET Extension Methods is basicaly provides partial application for first argument. F# pipelining oprators partial applies for last argument. All functions in Seq module takes sequence as last argument.

C#

```
seq.Where(...)
   .Select(...)
   .Take(...)
```

F#

```
seq
|> Seq.filter ...
|> Seq.map ...
|> Seq.take ...
```